# apt-get remove does not remove

Tags: apt, dhcpd

After I install, then remove a package, the application is still present:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'isc-dhcp-server' instead of 'dhcp3-server'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libindicate-gtk3 libindicate5 python-gst0.10 python-indicate
  python-twisted-words
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  isc-dhcp-server-ldap
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  isc-dhcp-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 762 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,138 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main isc-dhcp-server amd64 4.2.4-7ubuntu12 [762 kB]
Fetched 762 kB in 0s (3,544 kB/s)       
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package isc-dhcp-server.
(Reading database ... 437078 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../isc-dhcp-server_4.2.4-7ubuntu12_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking isc-dhcp-server (4.2.4-7ubuntu12) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up isc-dhcp-server (4.2.4-7ubuntu12) ...
Generating /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server...
isc-dhcp-server start/running, process 18678
isc-dhcp-server6 stop/pre-start, process 18732
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
```

```
$ sudo apt-get remove dhcp3-server

[sudo] password for gauthier: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'isc-dhcp-server' instead of 'dhcp3-server'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libindicate-gtk3 libindicate5 python-gst0.10 python-indicate
  python-twisted-words
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

```
$ dhcpd

Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.2.4
Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
unable to create icmp socket: Operation not permitted
Can't open /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases for append.
```

Why does `dhcpd` stay?

How can I remove it for real?

(Purge did not manage to remove the application either (of course, but at least I tried). The application was not installed before.)

Comment: Try to remove it using Synaptic Package Manager by selecting `Mark for Complete Removal`. After removing reboot.

Comment: @Guru the equivalent is `apt-get purge` or `apt-get remove --purge`.

Answer (score 5):

if you look at the output command, you have installed `isc-dhcp-server` instead of `dhcp3-server`. So all you have to do is

```
sudo apt-get remove isc-dhcp-server
```

Comment: So, this worked. BUT, I thought that was not necessary, since `sudo apt-get remove dhcp3-server` said: `Note, selecting 'isc-dhcp-server' instead of 'dhcp3-server'`. It sounds like apt tried to remove `isc-dhcp-server`, but did not manage. I had to write it. Since apt seemed to have made the connection not only on `install` but also on `remove`, why couldn't it remove it?

Answer (score 1):

use the command 
`sudo apt purge isc-dhcp-server`